# Spring Security Headers included, still getting 'Header Not Set' vulnerability warning

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-headers

I want to get rid of Header related vulnerability warnings. (**Missing X-Frame Header, Missing Content Type Header**)

I went through the Spring doc and made the required changes. But still getting those warnings (I'm using Owasap Zap security tool to validate vulnerability warnings)

Security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http create-session="never"  entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" >
    
        <security:headers>
            <security:content-type-options/>
            <security:frame-options/>    
        </security:headers>

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="_" password="_" authorities="_" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I've added the required dependencies in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version 4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version 4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the required servlet filter in the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This filter invokes a Spring bean (springSecurityFilterChain) which is an internal infrastructure bean created by the namespace to handle web security.